# How to increase View size with UITextview?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have made one sample demo ,When I type on `UITextview` it Will Expands but the view will not expand which is the super view of `UITextview`.

## Code

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
   CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
    textView.frame = newFrame;
   self.myTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;

    CGRect viewFrame = self.myCommentView.frame;
    viewFrame.size.height =self.myCommentView.frame.size.height + 1;
    viewFrame.origin.y=self.myCommentView.frame.origin.y - 1;
    self.myCommentView.frame =viewFrame;
    [self.myTextView layoutIfNeeded];
    [self.myCommentView layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

## Problem Is

View is not expanding with `UITextview`.And If View Is Expanded `UITextview` is not Expanding.

## Image

[image]

## UITextView Constraints

[image]

## StoryBoard

[image]
I want both should be expand when `UITextview` expand.

[image]
Thank You

Comment: Change your height constraint relationship from `=` to `>=`.

Comment: Not Working,Gives me error

Comment: Constraints are not proper.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to set constraint

Comment: Show me storyboard, and you are using `UITextview` not `UITextField`.

Comment: When i set >= instead of = of my view  it gives me error like, Missing Y position.

Comment: Ya I am using textview not text field.

Comment: Post your `storyboard` screen shot in your question.

Comment: Did i so something wrong?

Comment: what event was? tablview header?

Comment: If you are using `autoLayout`, you should update the constraints and not the frames. You are updating the frame in `textViewDidChange`, you should be updating the height constraint of your `UITextView` everytime a new line is added.

Comment: Ya that was header part.in between table view.and bottom new view with textview.

Comment: Bottom view is placed on table view.

Comment: How can i do this ?I mean updating height constraint.

Comment: So you mean textView is in footer??

Comment: @user7018875 check my answer that i post

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya `UITextView` is in `tableView` may be your code won't work.

Comment: @user7018875 are you really set Uitextview and view in tableview ?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya If textView is not in tableview then we don't need to write a single code we can manage it by the constraints. **IMP** taking constraints outlet is not in a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `UITextViewDelegate` delegates method.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *txtview;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *backgroundviewhight; // myview hight constrain. 
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *myview; 

_txtview.delegate = self; 



 - (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
 {
        CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
        CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
        CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
        newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
        textView.frame = newFrame;
        self.txtview.scrollEnabled = NO;
        _backgroundviewhight.constant = newFrame.size.height;
        [self.txtview layoutIfNeeded];
        [self.myview layoutIfNeeded];
  }
```

Your textview constrain like

[image: Your textview constrain]

create a constrain NSLayoutConstraint of your myview hight constrain

[image: Myview constrain]

Output:

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wzc42w1sulrx8yi/TEXTVIEW%20EXPAND.mov?dl=0)

Comment: Hey Where to connect  backgroundviewhight ,Because use IBOutlet

Comment: @user7018875 are you using this textview inside tableview ?

Comment: What About View constraints?

Comment: NO,I am using this textview in my view.(Dark blue).My whole view(dark blue)is different then tableview.

Comment: then in your question some user comment it so i ask you

Comment: @user7018875 just give constrain of your textview like me that 4 side and if no worry about spacing and after it make one outlet of your drak view and use it like i use in code .

Comment: Thanks a lot,Working fine,But one problem When i press Enter it consider as a character.Not a new line.So next line display after two time press enter.What can i do?

Comment: @user7018875 i did not face that kind of problem in my case . if you want to see that then i can update my output video .

Answer (score 0):

1.Set View constraint to Leading, Trailing, Bottom and fix it's height and make outlet of height constraint as **viewHeightConstraint**.

2.UITextView constraint to Leading, Trailing, Bottom and Top from superview(UIView).

3.In shouldChangeTextInRange delegate of UITextview get string height using the below methods

```
NSString *finalString = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];

/********** set width in width of your textview and font for your text in font ********/
       CGRect rect = [finalString boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){width   , CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                     options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin)
                                  attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}
                                     context:nil];
/** Now set the height for view as you type it will increase according with textView **/
    _viewHeightConstraint.constant = rect.size.height + 30;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my exprience you have to set **Top Constraint** to Comment View & set priority of your Comment View **(Low : 250)** like below.

**Set Priority :**

[image]

**Comment View Constraints:**

[image]

**Set TextView Constraints :**

[image]

**Minor update in your didTextChange Method:**

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{

    CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
    if (newSize.height>textView.frame.size.height) {
        [textView sizeToFit];
        textView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    }

    [textView layoutIfNeeded];

    [self.myCommentView layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

**Output :**

[image]

Hope this will helps you to set your resizable view.