# How To resize UITextView when it has only single line From the multiline With View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have made one UITextview Custom control with View.It is working fine.
When I enter for new line text view increases with view(Dark Blue).After this TextViell will working in form of scrolling.

## Code is

```
-(void)setTextViewHeight
{
    self.oldFrameHeight = self.commentTextView.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat fixedWidth = self.commentTextView.frame.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = [self.commentTextView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
    CGRect newFrame = self.commentTextView.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
    self.commentTextView.frame = newFrame;
    self.newFrameHeight = newFrame.size.height;
    NSLog(@"Old Frame %f",self.oldFrameHeight);
    NSLog(@"New Frame %f",self.newFrameHeight);
}
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{


    self.oldFrameHeight = textView.frame.size.height;


    if(!(self.oldFrameHeight >= 44))
    {
        [self setTextViewHeight];

        if (self.newFrameHeight  > self.oldFrameHeight)
        {
            [self sabViewFrameChange];
        }
    }
    else if ([textView.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        [self.commentTextView setFrame:CGRectMake(60, 10,self.frame.size.width - 130, 30)];

        UIViewController *controller=(UIViewController *)self.delegate;
        self.frame =  CGRectMake(0,controller.view.frame.size.height - 50, controller.view.frame.size.width,50);
        self.height = 50;
    }
    else
    {
        self.commentTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    }
}
```

## My Question Is

When I have removed second line from the UITextView the size will remain as it is,I did not decrease with line.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Image is

1) **With more then two line**

[image]

2) **With single line**

[image]

How can I resolve it ?Any one have any idea?

Comment: in your privious question answer also manage this. if you have single line then its also set your view for single line data. check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/41676540/6656894

Comment: No No Buddy That was  Absolutely right answer,I understood very well,But problem is that if I use that portion here every time it will call,No doubt it will resize textview accordingly but here it is not possible.

Comment: @Himanshu Moradiya :-I am only 3 month old fresher ,So I can not find correct solution,If you do not want to problem please send me your email I will send my demo code,Please.

Comment: got it thnks I will send

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `numLinesInTextView` variable

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text;
{
    NSLog(@"%@",text);
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
          NSLog(@"New line");
    }else{
        int numLines = [textView intrinsicContentSize].height / textView.font.lineHeight;
        NSLog(@"%f",textView.font.lineHeight);

        numLinesInTextView = numLines;
        if (numLinesInTextView == 0) {
            [self.commentTextView setFrame:CGRectMake(60, 10,self.frame.size.width - 130, 30)];
            UIViewController *controller=(UIViewController *)self.delegate;
            self.frame =  CGRectMake(0,controller.view.frame.size.height - 50, controller.view.frame.size.width,50);
            height = 50;
            numLinesInTextView = 0;
        }

    }
    return YES;
}
```

Add this method in your project and check it its working completely fine. now.

Happy Coding.